# batch insert into mysql using php

Tags: c#, php, mysql

We have an admin panel which uses php to insert rows into a mysql db but we can only insert one row at a time. We have hundreds of teachers who create hundreds of sentences and answers per week. How can we do a batch insert ie: They would create sentences in a spreadsheet or a c# utility and then would need to "upload" those sentences into mysql db. Not too sure how do do it and would welcome info. Thanks.

Link found in stackoverflow
[Batch insertion of data to MySQL database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042461/batch-insertion-of-data-to-mysql-database-using-php)

OK so I load a text file via php or I can use code in php which loops through each row and inserts it in the db.

So my question is if c# can do this and if not...
1. Each teacher copies and pastes their rows from their spreadhseet into a utility.
2. Export to a file that can then be uploaded to my db using php.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need it?

```
INSERT INTO `tbl` (`name`, `age`) VALUES ("name 1", 10), ("name 2", 11)
```

Insert many records at one time

Answer (score 0):

```
$Q0 = array();
$query0 = "INSERT INTO Table (`col1`,`col2`,`col3`) VALUES ";

            foreach($Q0 as $value0)
            {
                    $query0 .= "('$val1','$val2','$value0'),";
            }

            $query0 = substr_replace($query0, "", -1);
            mysqli_query($conn, $query0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in c#. First you need to give your teachers an excel format so they could fill the data (by an excel format I mean a blank excel file which has only column headers and they can fill the rows). Here is a couple of links that shows you how to get your data from excel.

[C# - How do I iterate all the rows in Excel._Worksheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727738/c-sharp-how-do-i-iterate-all-the-rows-in-excel-worksheet/12681669)

[Row Looping in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857321/row-looping-in-excel)

Then you can save the data in your database. This might give you and idea about how to do it.

[How do I to insert data into an SQL table using C# as well as implement an upload function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301582/how-do-i-to-insert-data-into-an-sql-table-using-c-sharp-as-well-as-implement-an)